# Websocket fails to start in ruby rails 7.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncable

I have been trying to set up an action cable with ruby on rails version 7.0.4 and fail to do
In the app/channels/application_cable.rb my configuration file is as below. As per official documentation, every connection should be identified, so I decided to identify that via random string:

module ApplicationCable
class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
identified_by: random_string

```
def random_string
  return SecureRandom.base64()
end
```

end
end

I have only a single channel, called room_channel for learning purposes:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
```

def subscribed
stream_from "room_channel"
end

def unsubscribed
# Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
end
end

in the app/javascript/channels/consumer.js I created below configuration and set up at least 1 consumer, so my app could work

```
import { createConsumer } from "@rails/actioncable"

export default createConsumer()

createConsumer(getWebSocketURL)

function getWebSocketURL() {
  return "ws://159.61.241.9:8000/cable"
}
```

My config/environments/development.rb file is as below for action cable related settings:

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:6379/cable"
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://159.65.241.9:8000']
  config.action_cable.mount_path="ws://localhost:6379/cable"
```

my cable.yml file in the config as below:

```
    development:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>


test:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>


production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: action_cable_chat_app_production
```

I started up the redis server already.
The error I end up with is as below:
[image]

Can someone please help me why WebSocket tries to start at 8000 port even though I mount the server in 6379 in the config file ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your JS

```
function getWebSocketURL() {
  return "ws://159.61.241.9:8000/cable"
}
```

It tries to connect to "ws://159.61.241.9:8000/cable", but you started at 6379 port. Change it to "ws://159.61.241.9:6379/cable". If 159.61.241.9 is not your public IP, than change to "ws://localhost:6379/cable"

Comment: I changed that. That didnt solve the issue